# UIKit Slideset setup

Tags: javascript, html, uikit

I'm trying to create an UIKit Slideset. Tried several times but I can't figure it out. If you familiar with it let me know how does it work. Here is my HTML code:

```html
<div data-uk-slideset="{default: 4}">
    <div class="uk-slidenav-position">
        <ul class="uk-grid uk-slideset">
            <li><img src="img/images1"</li>
             <li><img src="img/images1"</li>
             <li><img src="img/images1"</li>
             <li><img src="img/images1"</li>
             <li><img src="img/images1"</li>
             <li><img src="img/images1"</li>
             <li><img src="img/images1"</li>
             <li><img src="img/images1"</li>
             <li><img src="img/images1"</li>
             <li><img src="img/images1"</li>
             <li><img src="img/images1"</li>
             <li><img src="img/images1"</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" class="uk-slidenav uk-slidenav-previous" data-uk-slideset-item="previous"></a>
        <a href="" class="uk-slidenav uk-slidenav-next" data-uk-slideset-item="next"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="uk-slideset-nav uk-dotnav uk-flex-center">...</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've copy-pasted the example from the http://getuikit.com/docs/slideset.html into a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fL4876no/ with both the `slidenav`and the `dotnav`navigations active.

You can experiment with this yourself.

To keep in mind: you need to add the libraries for the slideset, slidenav and dotnav css & javascript.

If you want to see the working code on the getuikit.com website, i use the 'inspect element' function -right click in chrome- on the working examples.

There you can find more information than in the codesnippets provided.